# String to JSONObject in Android raise exception

Tags: java, android, json

Here is the JSON format in String object which i am trying to convert into JSONObject in android.

```
{  
   "city":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Mumbai"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Delhi"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "name":"Chennai"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "name":"Kolkatta"
      }
   ],
   "locality":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "locality_city_id":"1",
         "locality_name":"Andheri"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "locality_city_id":"1",
         "locality_name":"Bandra"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "locality_city_id":"1",
         "locality_name":"Dadar"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "locality_city_id":"1",
         "locality_name":"Thane"
      }
   ],
   "diseases":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "disease_name":"Blood Pressure"
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "disease_name":"Diebetes"
      },
      {  
         "id":"3",
         "disease_name":"Hypertention"
      },
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "disease_name":"Dyslexia"
      }
   ]
}
```

I copied it to JSON beautifier and it says it is a valid JSON.
But this raises exception. Is there anything wrong in the JSON format ?

Code used is:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Exception stacktrace:

> 08-11 11:22:33.548: W/System.err(3055): org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"city":[{"id":"1","name":"Mumbai"},{"id":"2","name":"Delhi"},{"id":"3","name":"Chennai"},{"id":"4","name":"Kolkatta"}],"locality":[{"id":"1","locality_city_id":"1","locality_name":"Andheri"},{"id":"2","locality_city_id":"1","locality_name":"Bandra"},{"id":"3","locality_city_id":"1","locality_name":"Dadar"},{"id":"4","locality_city_id":"1","locality_name":"Thane"}],"diseases":[{"id":"1","disease_name":"Blood
>   Pressure"},{"id":"2","disease_name":"Diebetes"},{"id":"3","disease_name":"Hypertention"},{"id":"4","disease_name":"Dyslexia"}]}
>   of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject 08-11
>   11:22:33.548: W/System.err(3055):     at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111) 08-11 11:22:33.548:
>   W/System.err(3055):   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:158) 08-11 11:22:33.548:
>   W/System.err(3055):   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:171)

Comment: Can you provide the exception?

Comment: you can get json objects from jsonarray for ex. JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
     JSONObject c = new JSONObject();  c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

Comment: this is an json array, and you are trying to make an object out of it, thats the issue !!

Comment: please provide full code and exeption

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You'll have to tell us what version of that library you are using.

Comment: I am using AQuery Android library AJAXCall for making server request. When tried directly as string it works. I guess the problem is with AQuery return type.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried with your JSON and the following code snippet works for me.

```
String strJson = YOUR_JSON_STRING_HERE;
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strJson);
    System.out.println(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Paste the whole code, because what ever you've provided works fine

Comment: Yes i tried it. Works fine. I guess there is some problem in return type of AJAX call used in AQuery Android library.